# How to merge two rows from a table into one in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table with the following columns and values.

```
Name Rate Kind NoOfItems TotalAmount
---- ---- ---- --------- -----------
ABC     1 O           50          50
ABC     2 A           10          20
```

(*) Table will have N names and the kind will be either O or A

I have to output the above table data as follows into a single row for each and every name.

```
Name O_Rate A_Rate O_Items A_Items O_Amount A_Amount TotalItems TotalAmount
---- ------ ------ ------- ------- -------- -------- ---------- -----------
ABC       1      2      50      10       50       20         60          70
```

How to convert the above mentioned table data as per the expected output using a single query. I have tried with Case and Decode but in both cases I am getting two rows only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data type is TotalAmount?  In Oracle  50$ does not exist, other than possibly as a string ('50$'). If it is string, should it be interpreted as a dollar amount before the values are added?

Comment: @mathguy TotalAmount field is of type number(10), the $ symbol in the example I have added for representation purpose only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to do this with conditional aggregation, but you can also use `join`:

```
select o.name, o.Rate as o_Rate, a.Rate as a_Rate,
       o.Kind as o_Kind, a.Kind as a_Kind,
       o.NoOfItems as o_NoOfItems, a.NoOfItems as a_NoOfItems,
       o.TotalAmount as o_TotalAmount, a.TotalAmount as a_TotalAmount,
      (o.NoOfItems + a.NoOfItems) as TotalItems,
      (o.TotalAmount + a.TotalAmount) as TotalAmount
from t o join
     t a
     on o.name = a.name and o.rate = 'O' and a.rate = 'A';
```

Comment: Missing: the totals. (Easy to add.)  The benefit of pivoting (either with conditional aggregation or with the PIVOT operator) is that the base table is read just once, instead of twice with this JOIN solution - and of course, there is no join either.

Answer (score 2):

Since Oracle 11.1 (I think) you can use the `PIVOT` operator, as shown below.

Better: it seems your so-called "input" is in fact an intermediate result, the output of other data processing. If so, you may be able to combine the PIVOT operation with what you are already doing - there is no reason to have it as a separate step, duplicating some of the work (and therefore some of the execution time). If you can show how you got the so-called "input" in the first place, we can show you how to integrate it with pivoting.

```
with
     test_data ( name, rate, kind, noofitems, totalamount ) as (
                 select 'ABC', 1, 'O', 50, 50 from dual
       union all select 'ABC', 2, 'A', 10, 20 from dual
     )
-- End of test data (not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select name, o_rate, a_rate, o_noofitems as o_items, a_noofitems as a_items,
       o_totalamount as o_amount, a_totalamount as a_amount,
       o_noofitems + a_noofitems as totalitems,
       o_totalamount + a_totalamount as totalamount
from   test_data
pivot(
       max(rate) as rate, max(noofitems) as noofitems, max(totalamount) as totalamount
       for kind in ('O' as o, 'A' as a)
     )
;

NAME  O_RATE  A_RATE  O_ITEMS  A_ITEMS  O_AMOUNT  A_AMOUNT  TOTALITEMS  TOTALAMOUNT
----  ------  ------  -------  -------  --------  --------  ----------  -----------
ABC        1       2       50       10        50        20          60           70
```